# Writing an API response to a .txt file

Tags: node.js

I am working with a nodejs app. I have developed a dummy API which works well.
This is a response I receive after hitting a get request endpoint.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "course1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "course2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "course3"
    }
]
```

My main objective is to able to save this response to a file, locally. However, my code returns something far from what I expected. It returns a huge amount of 'code' but an excerpt looks like:

```
function json (options) {
  var opts = options || {}

  var limit = typeof opts.limit !== 'number'
    ? bytes.parse(opts.limit || '100kb')
    : opts.limit
  var inflate = opts.inflate !== false
  var reviver = opts.reviver
  var strict = opts.strict !== false
  var type = opts.type || 'application/json'
  var verify = opts.verify || false
```

On the other hand, my code looks like this:

```
const courses = [
    {id:1, name:'course1'},
    {id:2, name:'course2'},
    {id:3, name:'course3'},
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
    res.send(courses)

    var write = fs.writeFile("Api.txt", json.toString(courses), (err) => {

        if (err) throw err 
        console.log(write)
    })
});
```

Can you spot my mistake or is there another way to do it? Please share. Thanks

Comment: what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

`json.toString` should be `JSON.stringify`. The reason you're getting JavaScript code saved to the file is: you have a `json` function defined *somewhere* in the code, and this you're calling `.toString()` on that function.

Since functions are objects in JS, you're accidentally telling JS to get a string representation of the "function object". By default, `Function.prototype.toString` is implemented as returning the source code.

Comment: I agree. I changed it and it worked so well . Thank you Robert .